# SQL Server Select Group by can't group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have this table:

```
ID  TXT VL 
----------
1   A   1
2   B   0
4   C   0
6   D   0
10  D   0
13  E   0
14  C   0
15  E   0
```

I have no idea how I can select only the first appearance of `TXT` like this:

```
ID  TXT VL 
----------
1   A   1
2   B   0
4   C   0
6   D   0
13  E   0
```

Comment: Assuming by first you mean lowest ID

Comment: Yes i need the first one only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
select t1.* 
from tbl t1 
join (select min(id) as id from tbl group by txt) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

In the temporary table you find all first occurrences of each uniq `txt` and then join it with the original table.

Comment: You don't really have to join the table to itself, just take group by txt + min/max/sum whatever you need for others

Comment: @JamesZ: It can cause wrong values in the `VL` column (For example, `1   A   0`, `2   A  1` : `sum` -> 1 (should be 0), `max` -> 1 (should be 0), `min` -> 0 (should be 0, but no backwords compability in case you swap id values))

Comment: Ah it was supposed to take the data of first row. The example doesn't really help figuring out that. In that case row_number() is the better option

Comment: If it is a large table, this will (As far as i know) not scale that well because of the self join.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER`, like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT *
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TXT ORDER BY ID) AS RowN
      FROM table
)
SELECT ID, TXT, VL
FROM CTE
WHERE RowN = 1
```

Hope it helps :)

For more reading:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx
And https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx